# Phaser 3 tween opacity?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to tween a sprite from one point to another and have it fade away while it's moving. I've tried this:

```
const tween = game.tweens.add({
  targets: [log.sprite],
  x: fire.x,
  y: fire.y + (fire.height * 0.2),
  opacity: 0,
  duration: 300,
  repeat: 0,
  onComplete() {
    destroyLog(log);
    resolve();
  },
});
```

But this doesn't work. I'm having a lot of trouble finding good API docs for Phaser 3, so I'm not sure where I should be looking for this information.

Comment: This may help you http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/8639-fade-out-text-after-2-second-delay/

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina That link is for Phaser 2. I made the mistake of getting a ways into this project with Phaser 3 before realizing the docs and examples are basically non-existent right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably should use `alpha` instead of `opacity`. Below is a working example for Phaser3. The start and end value lambdas are good just for flexibility. I guess you can replace them by values directly. `this` refers to Phaser.Scene instance.

```js
this.add.tween({
  targets: [sprite],
  ease: 'Sine.easeInOut',
  duration: 1000,
  delay: 0,
  x: {
    getStart: () => startX,
    getEnd: () => endX
  },
  y: {
    getStart: () => startY,
    getEnd: () => endY
  },
  alpha: {
    getStart: () => startAlpha,
    getEnd: () => endAlpha
  },
  onComplete: () => {
    // Handle completion
  }
});
```

You can easily find helpful usage examples for Phaser 3 by cloning the [repo](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser3-examples) locally and searching for some keywords in the code.

Comment: How can you remove or stop a tween ?